# Cython static link with python runtime?

Tags: python, windows, mingw, static-linking, cython

I have a Python script for python 2.7, say this:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Next I turn this into C using:

```
python cython.py --embed helloworld.py
```

And then I try to compile it statically:

```
gcc -IC:\Python27\include -LC:\Python27\libs helloworld.c -Wl,-Bstatic -lpython27
  -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

But gcc just creates a binary that uses the python27.dll runtime. How can I create a binary that statically links to the runtime?

Comment: you can't, you would need a static libpython27.a compiled with gcc, that currently not buildable (or at least officially), in activestate distribution you have python27.lib in \libs subdir but it links dynamic, I've just looked at this http://code.google.com/p/pts-mini-gpl/wiki/StaticPython, but windows is not supported (obviously)

Comment: Even when using Visual Studio, this can be troublesome, a few days ago I've been asking a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194489/cpython-sources-how-to-build-a-static-python26-lib

Answer (score 2):

If you are working from Linux or OS X, you can use [my engine's](http://ignifuga.org/) builder tool, Schafer, which has a "bare" mode which will just build Python statically (for all supported platforms, including Windows), along with several standard modules, and it will also "cythonize" and embed your sources into it as well. If this doesn't fit your bill, you still can get ideas from the [source](https://bitbucket.org/gabomdq/ignifuga) on what it takes to do what you want to accomplish.